# How can I replace the word with another in a string?

Tags: java

I have following xml string, In that I need to replace "dddomain1" with "dddomain"

I used the code below, but not working

```
xmlString.replaceAll("dddomain1","dddomain");
```

Comment: You don't have `xpsystems114` terms there

Comment: Are you assigning the result back?

Comment: You seem to have the arguments backwards. In any case don't use `replaceAll` - this is Regex and you don't need it. Use `String.replace`.

Answer (score 5):

You do not `need` to use the `replaceAll` method as this is for regexp.

try

```
xmlString = xmlString.replace("xpsystems114","xpsystems");
```

Comment: while true, I don't think that's an issue for "xpsystems114"

Comment: But nothing wrong with `replaceAll` in this case. I think your answer will work not because of `replace`, but because of the reassigning.

Comment: True nothing wrong. I guess the mistake was that he was not re-assigning it back to xmlString.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable. Any operation on returns a new String. Like @Maroun said, assign the returning reference to a String variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since `String` is immutable, `replaceAll()` returns a `new String` instead

```
String newXMLString = xmlString.replaceAll("xpsystems114", "xpsystems");
System.out.println(newXMLString);
```